# biblatex causing random letters appearing outside of my text environment

Tags: biblatex

I'm quite confused, when I first add a reference to my main document everything occurs normally, however after 1 or 2 additional 'Build & View' random letters and numbers begin to appear above my text environment. I would love a hand!

It should also be noted that when I remove  `\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=chem-acs]{biblatex}` the pesky letters disappear, but changing the bib style and backend do not alter them.

[image: PDF output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemscheme}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=chem-acs]{biblatex}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\addbibresource{introbib.bib}


\begin{document}

\section*{1.0 Introduction}

\subsection*{\textit{1.1 N-Heterocyclic Carbenes}}

N-heterocyclic carbenes (NHCs) have experienced a period of transformational growth in the field of organocatalysis, originating from the first successful isolation of a stable carbene in 1991.\autocite{ref1}


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

and .bib

```
@article{ref1,
  langid = {english},
  title = {A Stable Crystalline Carbene},
  volume = {113},
  issn = {0002-7863},
  url = {http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00001a054},
  doi = {10.1021/ja00001a054},
  number = {1},
  journaltitle = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
  urldate = {2019-01-16},
  date = {1991},
  pages = {361-363},
  author = {Arduengo, Anthony J. and Harlow, Richard L. and Kline, Michael},
  file = {C:\\Users\...\Arduengo et al. - 1991 - A stable crystalline carbene.pdf}
}
```

Comment: That really should not happen. I can't reproduce the issue with the code as shown (not least because I don't have `introbib.bib` containing a `ref1`, I used `sigfridsson` from `biblatex-examples.bib`). Do you get any errors or warning when you compile with LaTeX? I have seen similar symptoms before (usually these issues are caused by old or unexpected macros in the `.aux` files and so deleting the `.aux`, `.bbl` and `.bcf` might help if it's a one off), but then there should also be an error message (and the issue would not go away when you delete the `\usepackage{biblatex}`).

Comment: Please also check your `biblatex` and Biber versions for compatibility. If you want to, you can share the entire `.log` and `.blg` file on a text-sharing website such as https://pastebin.com/

Comment: I get no strange character after supplying a `.bib` file with the data you show.

Comment: Please add that `.bib` entry to your question. Even with the entry, I can not reproduce the issue shown in the question, however. Please also share your `.log` file with us.

Comment: Roger, will do now. I have just uploaded my .log file here  [link](https://pastebin.com/Kiy1HM3T)

Comment: .blg file is:

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99dThe top-level auxiliary file: Initial project overview.aux
The style file: biblatex.bst
Database file #1: Initial_project_overview-blx.bib
Database file #2: introbib.bib
Biblatex version: 3.3

Comment: Nothing in those log files suggests a relevant warning or error for the bibliography. As I say I can't reproduce the issue and egreg also did not get the problematic result earlier. Can you reduce your MWE further while still reproducing the issue (do you need `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}`? do your need `chemscheme`? etc. etc)?

Comment: All I can say is that your MikTeX installation is quite a bit older than what I have on my machine (your packages are from 2016 or before). Maybe this was a transient issue that has been fixed. If possible (i.e. time and deadlines permitting) you may want to try an update. Note that some internals of MikTeX changed last year and so there is a chance that you have to run multiple update sessions in admin and user mode to get things working again (there is also a small chance that because your system is so old it can't be updated cleanly).

Comment: Any news here? Did you attempt an update? If not, can you try to identify the problematic code more specifically? What packages can you remove from the MWE while still retaining the error? Do you need `auto-pst-pdf`, `chemscheme`, `setspace`, `chemnum`, `lipsum` (you are not using most of these in the example) etc.? Can you change the `biblatex` style to a standard style (`style=numeric` instead of `style=chem-acs`)

Comment: Hey Moewe, I think it may have been fixed with an update of MikTeX to 2.9.X. With regard to the additional packages, I had previous tried removing each individually to no avail. I greatly appreciate your help with it :) I hope I don't have to come back with the same issue at a later date!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by the OP themselves by updating MikTeX. The error could not be reproduced with the shown MWE.